# MongoDB Query ExpiredItem

Tags: mongodb, database

I have a question about an mongodb query.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("56e56d8a5fedaa00532886a4"),
"UserID" : "89",
"Trash" : [
    {
        "Type" : "File",
        "ID" : "56f948a4b9efe604ac217eb1",
        "ParentFolder" : "0",
        "ExpiredIn" : ISODate("2016-04-30T14:34:54.649+0000")
    },
    {
        "Type" : "Folder",
        "ID" : "57f918a4b8efe604ac227eb5",
        "ParentFolder" : "0",
        "ExpiredIn" : ISODate("2016-04-27T14:34:54.649+0000")
    }
]
```

}

I need the items, that are expired. How can I do this? Some mongo queries are so difficult.

Kind regards
Hendrik

Comment: you mean to say you want all the documents where `ExpiredIn < Today`

Answer (score 1):

The aggregation framework is ideal for such. Consider running the following pipeline to get the desired result.

```
pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": { "Trash.ExpiredIn": { "$lte": new Date() } }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "ExpiredTrashItems": {                                  
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$Trash",
                    "as": "el",
                    "cond": { "$lte": [ "$$el.ExpiredIn", new Date() ] }
                }                                   
            }
        }
    }
]
db.collection.pipeline(pipeline)
```

The above pipeline uses the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)** operator available for MongoDB 3.2 to produce an array which meets the specified condition i.e. it filters outer elements that do not satisfy the criteria.

---

For an alternative solution which does not use the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)** operator, consider

```
pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": { "Trash.ExpiredIn": { "$lte": new Date() } }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "ExpiredTrashItems": {                              
                "$setDifference": [
                    {
                        "$map": {
                            "input": "$Trash",
                            "as": "el",
                            "in": {
                                "$cond": [
                                    { "$lte": [ "$$el.ExpiredIn", new Date() ] },
                                    "$$el",
                                    false
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    [false]
                ]                                   
            }
        }
    }
]
db.collection.pipeline(pipeline)
```

The **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline stage involves filtering the `Trash` array so that you remove the documents which haven't yet expired i.e. their `ExpiredIn` field is greater than the current date time. This filtering is made possible through the **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** and [**`$map`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map) operators.

The [**`$map`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map) operator in essence creates a new array field that holds values as a result of the evaluated logic in a subexpression to each element of an array. The **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** operator then returns a set with elements that appear in the first set but not in the second set; i.e. performs a relative compliment of the second set relative to the first. In this case it will return the final `Trash` array that has elements with `ExpiredIn` date less than or equal to the current date time i.e. already expired.

---

For a solution that uses the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator, although not ideal as it produces a copy of each document per array entry thus uses more memory and will take more time to process than previous methods, run the following
pipeline:

```
pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": { "Trash.ExpiredIn": { "$lte": new Date() } }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$Trash" },
    {
        "$match": { "Trash.ExpiredIn": { "$lte": new Date() } }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null
            "ExpiredTrashItems": { "$push": "$Trash" }
        }
    }
]
db.collection.pipeline(pipeline)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
db.document.find({
    "Trash": {
        $elemMatch: {
            "ExpiredIn": {
                $lt: new Date()
            }
        }
     }
})
```

Comment: Please explain your solution in order to make it a good acceptable answer..